# Render images on drag-and-drop, using javascript and handlebars

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, handlebars.js

I am trying to render multiple images in a div, using drag-and-drop technique.

But I am not getting expected results, and no matter what I tried, I was
getting images repeated, and `name`, `size` and `type` attributes being overridden.

**EDIT**
Ok, I realised why I am getting an empty `data` array. It's because at that
time `onload` event didn't finish, so no data still available.

But now I don't know how to resolve the PROBLEM which is defined bellow in a
comment, on how to render template just ONCE when all files are loaded.

Can anybody give some clue about how this data should be prepared to be rendered later calling Handlebars?

**js/filedrop.js**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    // define the drop zone
    var dropZone = document.getElementById("drop-zone");

    // add  a drag over event to the zone
    dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a hover class so we can see it's working
        dropZone.setAttribute("class", "over");
    }, false);

    // on file drop grab all available image information
    dropZone.addEventListener("drop", function(e){
        "use strict";

        e.preventDefault();

        var
        reader,
        files = e.dataTransfer.files,
        fileCount = files.length,
        i;

        // get the Handlebars template
        var handlebarTemplate = document.getElementById("handlebar-template");
        var template = Handlebars.compile(handlebarTemplate.innerHTML);

        if(fileCount > 0){
            var data = [], currObj = {};

            for(i = 0; i < fileCount; i = i + 1){
                var file = files[i];

                reader = new FileReader();

                // remove the hover class
                dropZone.removeAttribute("class");

                reader.onload = function(e){
                    currObj = {
                        name : file.name,
                        size : file.size,
                        type : file.type,
                        source: e.target.result
                    };
                    data.push(currObj);

                    // PROBLEM, how to load template once all files are loaded
                    // because leaving it like this will load some files multiple times
                    // also name, size and type attributes will be overwritten so I will get
                    // same attributes for all loaded images.
                    dropZone.innerHTML += ( template(data) );
                };
                // render the image as a data url
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } //end for loop
            //console.log(data); I got this! See above EDIT


        } //end if
    }, false); //end listener
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Chapter 12</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #drop-zone {
                min-height: 300px;
                max-width: 300px;
                padding: 15px;
                border: 4px dashed #999;
            }
            #drop-zone img {
                max-width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
            .over {
                border-color: #333;
                background: #ddd;
            }
            ul {
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
                color: #333;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="drop-zone">
            <script id="handlebar-template" type="text/x-handlebars-temlate">
                <div class="img-slot">
                    {{#each this}}
                    <img src="{{source}}" alt="{{name}}">
                    <ul>
                        <li>{{name}}</li>
                        <li>{{type}}</li>
                        <li>{{size}}</li>
                    </ul>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>

            </script>
        </div><!-- /#drop-zone -->

        <script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filedrop.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tweaking and thinking, finally I made it work.
Please see in-file comments, for an explanation on how I resolved the issue.

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    // define the drop zone
    var dropZone = document.getElementById("drop-zone");

    ...
    ...

    // on file drop grab all available image information
    dropZone.addEventListener("drop", function(e){
        "use strict";

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the Handlebars template instance
        var handlebarTemplate = document.getElementById("handlebar-template"),
            template = Handlebars.compile(handlebarTemplate.innerHTML);

        // declare some variables
        var reader,
            files = e.dataTransfer.files,
            i;

        if(files.length > 0){
            var data = [], f;

            for(i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++){
                reader = new FileReader();

                // have control over which file is being processed by
                // wrapping it all into another anonymous function and
                // passing `theFile` argument from loop iteration
                reader.onload = (function(theFile){
                    return function(e){

                        var imgObj = {
                            name: theFile.name,
                            type: theFile.type,
                            size: theFile.size,
                            source: e.target.result
                        };
                        data.push(imgObj);

                        // check if all files loaded, so we can then handover to Handlebars.js
                        if (data.length == files.length){
                            renderTemplate();
                        }
                    }
                })(f);
                // render the image as a data url
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            } //end for loop
        } //end if

        // Handover data to Handlebars.js
        function renderTemplate(){
            dropZone.innerHTML += ( template(data) );
        }
    }, false); //end listener
})();
```